# Call stored procedure using method name in a variable in postgres

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

The following Statement show error

```
EXECUTE quote_ident('Calculate' || calc_type_row."Name") || '($1,$2)' USING calc_type_row."IntervalTypeId",'Meter';
```

`Name`, `IntervalTypeId` are column in a table.

Comment: please specify the error message

Comment: syntax error at or near ""CalculateTotal""

Answer (score 3):

The statement `EXECUTE` is expecting valid `SQL` statement - in this case `SELECT` statement. So you are missing `SELECT` keyword:

```
EXECUTE format ('SELECT %I($1, $2)', 'Calculate' || calc_type."Name") USING ...
```